# Скрипт на удаление пробела

Tags: javascript, скрипт

Как сделать так чтобы быстро удалить пробел из ссылки и вставить в браузер из дискорда

Comment: Если пробелы в конце строки или в начале то можно обычный trim (blabla.trim())

Comment: А если этот пробел в середине?

Comment: `.replace(/ /g, '')`

Comment: По вашему вопросу мало что понятно. Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее. Где появляется "ссылка"? Она появляется как обычная браузерная ссылка (HTML элемент `a`), на которую можно нажать? Или просто адрес страницы появляется как текст, который нужно выделить и скопировать? И куда вы собираетесь её вставлять? В адресную строку, чтобы открыть в браузере? В поле формы, чтобы куда-то отправить?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример простой регулярки:

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Comment: Это в javascript вставлять или как это работает?

Comment: Да. str это Ваша строка

Comment: Я до конца не понят что с этим делать вот у нас есть ссылка, браузер и эта строка как это совместить?

Comment: Эм, в самом урле браузера вы ниче не сделаете, только в ручную